# Is there an easy way to back out of this on git?

Tags: git, circleci

In circleCI, the way it clones and checks out stuff leaves the repo in a weird state where master has changes (the developer submitted a branch called submit_xxx/xxx and can't touch master if he wanted to).  The state of circleCI is that it starts on the branch but then we run git checkout master in CI resulting in this

```
#!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 4 commits.
   (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
CircleCI received exit code 0
```

this is just ODD and we need master to be clean.  How to revert this where it may be 4 commits, 5 commits.  We want to just blow it away.  is this possible?

thanks,
Dean

Comment: If you're really sure, use `git reset --hard origin/master`, or—as long as you have to do a `git checkout` in the first place—consider `git checkout -B master origin/master` as the checkout step. Note the uppercase B option here. Either way this can lose data, so be careful.

Comment: cool, since it's in CI, it's not losing data, and it is all working like a charm now.  thanks!